# Where to find the template for sale emails in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, email-templates

I can't find where Magento keeps template which generates sales items in the sale emails. I need to change the colour bar on where it holds `Item, Sku, Qty, Subtotal`

[image]

I go to `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourTemplate/layout/` and open `sales.xml`, still can't find any hint of it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/email/order/items.phtml

```
<?php  $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<table class="data-table" id="my-orders-table" summary="<?php echo $this->__('Items Ordered') ?>">
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?></th>
            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
    </tfoot>
        <?php $_items = $_order->getItemsCollection(); ?>
        <?php $_index = 0; ?>
            <?php $_count = $_items->count(); ?>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
        <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; ?>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php if($this->helper('giftmessage/message')->getIsMessagesAvailable('order_item', $_item) && $_item->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
            <tr class="border<?php echo ($_index++ > $_count ?' last':'') ?>" id="order-item-gift-message-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php $_giftMessage=$this->helper('giftmessage/message')->getGiftMessageForEntity($_item); ?>
                <td class="gift-message-row" colspan="7">
                    <a href="#" title="<?php echo $this->__('Close') ?>" onclick="return giftMessageToogle('<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>');" class="btn-close"><?php echo $this->__('Close') ?></a>
                    <dl class="gift-message">
                        <dt><strong><?php echo $this->__('From:') ?></strong> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?></dt>
                        <dt><strong><?php echo $this->__('To:') ?></strong> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $this->helper('giftmessage/message')->getEscapedGiftMessage($_item) ?></dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endif ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-orders-table', {'tbody' : ['odd', 'even'], 'tbody tr' : ['first', 'last']})</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The file is 
`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/email/order/items.phtml`.
You need to edit the `<thead>` section.

Comment: I found it. But why it has no style of colour in `<thead>` but I get the grey colour in my email? Please see my edit above.

Comment: Also, it says `Product Name` but it is `Item` in my email.

Comment: Oh I got it. I was looking at the wrong file!  Thanks!#